# How to terminate last function in chaining method php

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining, fluent-interface

I got some problem and I don't know how to fix it.

this is sample for the problem

```
class DancingClass {
    private static $associate = [];
    private static $first;

    public static function first($param) {
        self::$first = $param;

        return new self;
    }

    public function second($param) {
        self::$associate["second"] = $param;

        return new self;
    }

    public function finish() {
        var_dump(self::$associate["second"]);
        $sec = self::$associate["second"] | "";

        $all = self::$first . " ditemani oleh " . $sec;

        return $all;
    }
}
```

Then I call with chaining method

```
$callingClass = new DancingClass;

echo $callingClass::first("lucky")->second("adhitya")->finish(); // Return "lucky ditemani oleh adhitya"
echo "<br/>";

echo $callingClass::first("fatur")->finish(); // Return "fatur ditemani oleh"
```

but I got result like this
[image: the result]

Comment: Could you please describe your purpose of this question. what do you need to do specifically with this approach and why you need to follow this using `static` members?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `second()` method it sets variable on the same class instance that you call later.

Maybe you should try:

```
echo ((new DancingClass())->first(...)->second(...)->finish();
echo ((new DancingClass())->first(...)->finish()
```

Comment: it's running, but still got same result